# HTML5 datalist does not recognize numbers in autocomplete function

Tags: html, html-datalist

I am trying to implement an input field with datalist that contains numbers only. I have noticed that the datalist's autocomplete functions does not work for datalist values that are equal to numbers.

How can I make the autocomplete function work for numeric values?

**EXAMPLE**

```html
<h2>Text datalist</h2>
<p>Try typing "Greece"</p>
<input id="text" list="textList" />
<datalist id="textList">
  <option>Greece</option>
  <option>Italy</option>
  <option>Spain</option>
</datalist>

<h2>Number datalist</h2>
<p>Try typing a number (no autocomplete function)</p>
<input id="num" list="numList" />
<datalist id="numList">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>0</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see how datalist works:

> If there is **only one character** in the option and you type it , there
> is no reason to show that already typed character in dropdown

Thus if there is

```
<datalist id="textList">
  <option>g</option>
  <option>i</option>
  <option>s</option>
</datalist>
```

then type in `i`,`g` or `s` will not populate the list, **because it is already typed, the full word**

Similar for numbers(datalist will **NOT consider numbers and text differently**)

```
<datalist id="textList">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </datalist>
```

will not work,

Instead try this:

```
 <datalist id="textList">
          <option>01</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>22</option>
        </datalist>
```

this will of-course work **until you type the complete word which matched an option**(at this moment there will be no need to show the same thing in dropdown)

---

This always happen, for example, your code:

```
<datalist id="textList">
  <option>Greece</option>
  <option>Italy</option>
  <option>Spain</option>
</datalist>
```

what happens when you type in `Greece`, the whole text fromm option, it disappears, isn't it. so that is exactly what is happening with you when there is just one character in option.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byfzwa6h/1/)

Comment: Thanks Naeem! That was so simple!

Comment: It seems that this is not the case anymore, on the current version of Chrome, typing any number will display the datalist regardless of it being a single digit